# Document macro without expansion

Tags: macros, doxygen

In my C project which I'm documenting using doxygen 1.9.1, I've got several documented macros such as

```c
/**
 * @brief Does a thing.
 */
#define DO_THING() someFunc(1, 2, 3)
```

When I generate the documentation, `DO_THING` is listed but it shows the expansion (i.e., `someFunc(1, 2, 3)`).  Is there any way to have doxygen hide the expansion?  I'd like my macros to be opaque to my users.  That is, I'd like them to only know, "There's a macro called `DO_THING()` and it does a thing."

Comment: What settings are you using different from the default settings (i.e. the result of `doxygen -x Doxyfile`) and paste them into your question. The doxygen version 1.9.1 is from January 8 2021, the current doxygen version is 1.9.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doxygen has the possibility to set the maximum number of initializer lines by means of the setting: `MAX_INITIALIZER_LINES`

> MAX_INITIALIZER_LINES
>
> The MAX_INITIALIZER_LINES tag determines the maximum number of lines that the initial value of a variable or macro / define can have for it to appear in the documentation. If the initializer consists of more lines than specified here it will be hidden. Use a value of 0 to hide initializers completely. The appearance of the value of individual variables and macros / defines can be controlled using \showinitializer or \hideinitializer command in the documentation regardless of this setting.

and has the command `\hideinitializer`

> \hideinitializer

> By default the value of a define and the initializer of a variable are displayed unless they are longer than 30 lines. By putting this command in a comment block of a define or variable, the initializer is always hidden. The maximum number of initialization lines can be changed by means of the configuration parameter MAX_INITIALIZER_LINES, the default value is 30.

So you can solve your problem by either setting

- `MAX_INITIALIZER_LINES` to `0  though this is valid for all initialized values
- for the relevant parts the `\hideinitializer`